# Is my definition of improper integral ok?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

I am reading a calculus book.

I have a question about the definition of improper integral.

The improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ is defined as follows:

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx:=\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx + \lim_{b\to\infty}\int_{c}^{b}f(x)dx.$$

In this definition, the author used two different variables $a,b$.

But I think the following definition is the same as the above definition:

> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx:=\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx + \lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{c}^{a}f(x)dx.$$

Why did the author use two different variables?

And I don't like the above definitions.

Is the following definition of mine ok?

> We define $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx$ ***if and only if both of $\lim_{a\to-\infty}\int_{a}^{c}f(x)dx$ and $\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{c}^{a}f(x)dx$ converge*** as follows:
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)dx:=\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx$$

Comment: Improper integral in the sense of Cauchy principal value.

Comment: A problem occurs when you have something like $\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$ where the initial definition fails to converge (you get $-\infty+\infty$) but your final proposal does.  The reason the second definition might not be used is that it could be confusing to readers as to whether the two $a$s moving to the limit are different or equal (they are different as they are going to different limits, but this requires extra thought to spot)

Comment: there are no "variables" involved in these expressions. The concept of "variable" is not used in mathematics, perhaps in physics or chemistry

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: @Masacroso The concept of variable is very well used in Mathematics. What do you mean by this?

Comment: @Miguel I mean that I never read a book of mathematics with the word "variable" in it. And I had read more than 30-50 books of mathematics at this time. EDIT: well, there is an exception in the use of the words "random variable".

Comment: @Masacroso There's a whole field of Mathematics called "multivariable calculus". Arguments of functions are usually called variables. When you perform a derivative, you do it with respect to a variable. And so on...

Comment: @Miguel all calculus books are not written for mathematicians if not for engineers, physicists and other related disciplines. In mathematics the concept of variable is never used or defined.

Comment: @Masacroso I don't know if you are trolling or serious. In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(mathematics) you have a lot of non-engineering or physics uses of the word "variable".

Comment: Just to amplify @Alexander's comment: your definition is called the [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) of $f$. It is defined for a wider range of functions; for instance, the Cauchy principal value of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3$ is zero, but the improper integral is undefined.